# Layout issues with web views when changing iPad orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview, orientation

I'm having trouble when I flip my iPad app around to landscape mode.  When I do this, the formatting of the web views gets all screwed up.
[image: Portrait mode screen shot]

This is when it is in portrait mode. There is a scroll view which is the subview of the view controller, and within the scroll view there are three web views which you can scroll between by swiping left and right.

This is what happens when it goes into Landscape mode:
[image: Landscape mode screenshot]

Any ideas as to why this is?  All the settings in Interface Builder (the frame margin settings, autoresize subviews, etc.) are all correct, but I can't seem to figure out why it does what it does.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem in my previous project. I solved the problem by reloading the content during the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation callback. Any better solutions?

Comment: can you post some code for me? where is the did RotateFrominterfaceOrientation method?

Comment: I got the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. but, when you say reloaded the content, do you mean you just simply changed the size of the frames that you were using?

Comment: Ctac, did you figure? Have the same problem my self. I had no success in reload from didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047145/uitoolbar-disturbs-scrollview-when-changing-ipad-orientation-constraint-setting